# Connecting MongoDB to local DB file

Tags: mongodb

I've downloaded the production mongodb and dropped the folder with the data into my documents directory under a folder titled `project1`. I'm noticing that launching mongo with the following command `mongod --port 3000 --dbpath ~/Documents/project/prod/` and then following that up with a `mongo --port 3000` isn't causing the shell to find the database. The db itself should be called `pord`. Im wondering what am I not doing correctly. How does one get MongoDB to use a database that they've downloaded, its looking like specifying the local path isn't working.

Comment: Does `show dbs` yield nothing?

Comment: yup, `show dbs` doesn't display the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to actually use `mongorestore` feature. The command is `mongorestore -d db_name_here -c collection_name_here ~/path/to/file`